# ffmpeg cannot convert swf to video or gif

Tags: flash, video, ffmpeg, gif

I'trying to convert some swf files to video or gif using ffmpeg but the output is strange. it has only some images or nothing.

[Here](http://www.flashppt.com/resources/flash-samples.html) is my swf files. It just a very simple swf and i think it could be converted.

Can every swf files be converted to gif/video using ffmpeg?
Which can and which cannot?

Comment: Is your swf interactive or a straight video file?

Comment: I'm not sure, may be it's not a video file. I just downloaded it from internet for testing. http://www.flashppt.com/resources/flash-samples.html